# How to create zip of folder and download zip in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to create and download zip of a folder in my custom module.
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860813/create-a-zip-file-of-a-folder-and-download-it-using-php) link, but getting fatal error **`Uncaught Error: Class 'Vendor\Module\Controller\Custom\ZipArchive' not found.`**
How to accomplish this. please help.

Comment: Please update your code, so that we can able to identify the error. It seems the file not there or may be wrong namespace. Can you please check it.

Comment: It's look like class path is not correct. Can you please try to put some text in your function and then write die; check this text display or not.

Comment: My controller is working but when i introduce **$zip = new ZipArchive;** this shows fatal error. Can you please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860813/create-a-zip-file-of-a-folder-and-download-it-using-php).

Comment: new ZipArchive. It means ZipArchive is php function not a magento function. Can you please check ziparchive  php extension is installed or not.

Comment: try withthis `new \ZipArchive()`

Comment: Zip extension is installed and enable too. But, i think at some point magento restricts ZipArchive or may be i am attempting to include it in wrong way

Comment: Magento trying to find ZipArchive at your `Vendor\Module\Controller\Custom` directory and as it is not there it shows that error so You need to add "\" like this `new \ZipArchive()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a model file in your module.

File: MageExt/Download/Model/CustomDownload.php

```
<?php

namespace MageExt\Download\Model;

class CustomDownload
{
    protected $directoryList;
    protected $driver;
    protected $fileFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Shell\Driver $driver,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
    )
    {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->driver = $driver;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    }

    public function downloadCustomDocs()
    {
        if (!class_exists('\ZipArchive')) {
            die('ZipArchive class not found');
        }

        $dir = $this->directoryList->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::ROOT);
        //chdir($dir.'/app/code/CustomDocs');
        $rootPath = $dir.'/app/code/CustomDocs';
        chdir($rootPath);
        //$this->driver->execute('zip -r ../CustomDocs.zip *', []);
        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $zip->open('CustomDocs.zip', \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
            \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach ($files as $name => $file)
        {
            // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
            if (!$file->isDir())
            {
                // Get real and relative path for current file
                $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

                // Add current file to archive
                $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
            }
        }

        $zip->close();

        $this->fileFactory->create(
                'CustomDocs.zip',
                [
                    'type' => 'filename',
                    'value' => $dir.'/app/code/CustomDocs/CustomDocs.zip',
                    'rm' => true
                ],
                \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::ROOT,
                'application/zip'
            );
    }
}
```

Now you can call downloadCustomDocs() function from anywhere in your module.

Comment: can you please explain it by adding comments. i am getting cofused.

Comment: Tell me the Vendor name, Module name and folder to zip inside your module ..

Comment: Vendor: MageExt, Module: Download. But the folder needs to download is in app/code directory, which is parallel to the module directory. The name of directory is "CustomDocs",

Comment: Let me know the folder path including name of the folder which you want to download.

Comment: Folder path : **app/code/CustomDocs** which need to download.

Comment: Just updated the answer with exact code. If you still have any confusion, do let me know on what action you want it to download.

Comment: Getting **"File not found"** error. Actually **CustomDocs** is a folder, i think first i should create a zip and then download it. If it is so, can you please tell me about builtin feature to create a zip from directory?

Comment: Yes it is coded in that sequence only. There should be a directory "CutomDocs" and i assume there are certain files inside it.

Comment: Yes CutomDocs is a directory with subfolders and files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89723/discussion-between-yash7690-and-iqbal-malik).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is any structural (class added or class name/reference modified) in your modeule: 
Or
Any JS/Less file contents change in your theme:
You need to build your static content again and setup compile again as well.
(There is a set of commands for this already)

Otherwise your changes will not be picked..